# Is there a term for a recipe inside a recipe?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, food

Many recipes often have a "sub-recipe" inside of them. Such as a cake recipe having a separate section for the icing. Other recipes will have a sub-recipe for the sauce. Is there a formal cooking term for this?

According to Google a "sub recipe" is for making submarine sandwiches and a "mini recipe" is for small sized versions of things like cupcakes.

Comment: A lemon lemma maybe?

Comment: You give examples with one recipe being used _with_ not _inside_ the other. Must the two recipe "parts" be combined into one to satisfy your question?

Comment: @jimm101 ... or a meringue harangue.

Comment: [cooking.se] might be a better place to ask, since this term would be specialized to their community.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the quotation marks from "sub-recipe," because that's the correct term, at least in recipes and recipe books. I haven't found a dictionary definition; however, *subrecipe* and *parent recipe* are terms used in other fields as well.

**subrecipe/sub-recipe**

> What is a sub-recipe?
> **Keywords: subrecipe, sub-recipe**
>
> **A sub-recipe is
> a recipe that is used as a component in a parent recipe.**
>
> Sub-recipes are used to simplify the parent recipe by breaking the
> recipe up into smaller recipes that reflect their production (e.g., a
> sub-recipe tomato sauce gets prepared before assembling a pasta dish).
>
> [Sam Sinsky;
> 'Galley'](https://help.galleysolutions.com/en/articles/3270411-what-is-a-sub-recipe)

---

> I've included ten recipes for homemade mixers in the **subrecipe**
> section of this book... [Jim Meehan; *Meehan's Bartender Manual*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Meehan_s_Bartender_Manual/3ic2DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22subrecipe%22&pg=PA75&printsec=frontcover).

> See the **subrecipe** for Pizza Dough. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/One_Sheet_Eats/82I-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22see%20the%20subrecipe%20for%20pizza%20dough%22).

> The recipe for Miso Soup with Tofu, Shiitakes, Noodles, and Baby
> Spinach (page 64) includes a **subrecipe** for homemade dashi. [Catherine Jones et al.; *The Calories In Calories Out Cookbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Calories_In_Calories_Out_Cookbook/PjnnAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22subrecipe%22&pg=PA341&printsec=frontcover).

> They also indicate clearly when the time to make a **subrecipe**, such as
> a crust or frosting, is not included in the overall time. You'll will need to remember to factor in the time to make those **subrecipes**. [Carolyn Ketchum; *The Ultimate Guide to Keto baking*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Ultimate_Guide_to_Keto_Baking/ZFy8DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22subrecipe%22&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover).

> Both **sub-recipe** and preparation are things that you make in bulk,
> in house. This can be pizza dough, tomato sauce, slices of tomatoes,
> or even kits of napkin-fork-knife. [Jordan Silverman; 'Preparations and Sub-Recipes'](https://marketman.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001834052-Preparations-and-Sub-Recipes).

Comment: Please attribute correctly. It's required on ELU, respectful, helpful to readers in judging authority of source, and less likely to be seen as breach of copyright.

Comment: Will do. Is there a minimum length that requires the source name?

Comment: Doubtless, for legal requirements. On ELU, any quote used as evidence / support should be attributed, for the other reasons above.